# array data sorting like mysql query

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, sorting

I have multidimensional associative array like below, and printing this on the page in a html table, Now i want to do the functionality for the table like pagination, sorting on columns. I am looking for the library that can do the job.

I have googled this but could not find a sufficient idea to do the job. Read about array_multisort and other array functions.

Actually i want to run the query once and fill data into array. Other function like `order by(sorting)` and `limit(pagination)` done through the array without re-execute the query.

Array can have all data types.

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [trans_date_time] => 30-07-2008 11:35:16
            [transaction_value] => 16.95
            [affiliate_earns] => 0.51
            [programme_name] => Buy Cosmetics
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [trans_date_time] => 26-07-2006 13:37:31
            [transaction_value] => 5.99
            [affiliate_earns] => 
            [programme_name] => hmv
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [trans_date_time] => 16-08-2006 12:27:21
            [transaction_value] => 6.40
            [affiliate_earns] => 
            [programme_name] => Good
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [trans_date_time] => 09-09-2008 09:31:07
            [transaction_value] => 219.14
            [affiliate_earns] => 45.00
            [programme_name] => AIG Home insurance
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [trans_date_time] => 06-09-2006 10:05:22
            [transaction_value] => 7.50
            [affiliate_earns] => 
            [programme_name] => Better
        )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do this all on the client side with JavaScript, displaying certain rows of the table..

Answer (score 1):

where is your code man?  you can use pagination at the very beginning at the time of data fetching from the database.
anyway, you can get a working code on pagination from http://www.scriptforyou.com. 
also it is here:

```
<?php
/*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 2;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">� previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    // Your while loop here

    }
?>

<?=$pagination?>
```

and css for this:

```
div.pagination {
padding: 3px;
margin: 3px;
}

div.pagination a {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin: 2px;
border: 1px solid #AAAADD;

text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
color: #000099;
}
div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
border: 1px solid #000099;

color: #000;
}
div.pagination span.current {
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000099;

    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #000099;
    color: #FFF;
}
div.pagination span.disabled {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;

    color: #DDD;
}
```

this is really help you. make some changes according to your need. happy coding!

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` Instead. Also, he's looking for a function to sort arrays MySQL like

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the usort function then:

```
function my_custom_sorter($a, $b) {
    if($a['key_name'] == $b['key_name']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['key_name'] < $b['key_name']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($my_array, 'my_custom_sorter');
```

You could define some variable globally of what to sort by and then use that within the sorter function to comapre the right keys.

PHP Ref: http://uk.php.net/usort